# Fazer download de audio com unity no android

Tags: c#, android, unity-5

Estou tentando fazer o download de um audio, no editor o download funciona, porém após instalado o apk no celular, ele faz o download do arquivo, soque não completo, ele salva um arquivo de 40b, enquanto o arquivo salvo no editor tem 147kb, eu estou usando um script que achei no GitHub, link [aqui](https://gist.github.com/darktable/2317063)

Comment: Olá. Primeiramente, não coloque um link para um código externo. Procure colocar o código diretamente na pergunta. Se não sabe como fazer, dê uma olhada na [help]. Em segundo lugar, o código que vc cita apenas salva um AudioClip no disco em formato Wav. Vc diz que está fazendo download, mas não colocou o código de como faz o download. Em outras palavras: qual é a origem do seu AudioClip? Vc tem certeza que ele já não está com apenas o equivalente a 40 bytes quando vc pede pra salvar em disco? Tente executar o áudio num AudioPlayer antes de salvar pra ter certeza que está completo.